# Theoretically iterating through memory addresses?

Tags: c++, memory, iteration, memory-address

Just as the question asks:

What would happen if you iterated through memory, or chose random memory addresses assigning random data?

Surely there is some protection against this, but I'm not going to try it out just in case.

I know this seems like such a childish question, but it's in the name of curiosity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to access a memory address that isn't assigned to your process, or you violate access control (e.g. try to write to an address that's marked read-only), you'll most likely trigger a trap (Segmentation Violation on Unix, Memory Protection Error on Windows).

If you write random data into some accessible part of your memory, you'll probably corrupt a data structure used by your program, perhaps overwriting critical parts of the stack or bookkeeping data for the heap. This will cause the program to behave unpredictably, and may or may not result in a trap.

Answer (score 3):

I really depends on the OS.

In all modern OS's, the memory is indeed protected in the sense that only memory that is actually available to your application is given a virtual address translation (your application will probably have the same virtual address as another application of a different kind, but using different physical addresses).

Accessing memory that isn't "mapped" (virtual address doesn't have a translation to physical address) will cause a "page-fault", which the OS then checks to see if the memory is actually supposed to be there (it may have been swapped out to disk), and if that doesn't come up with something, it fails the operation, which typically ends your program.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to satisfy your curiosity about your address space is to examine the memory map for some process.  For example, if you're on Linux, try:

```
$ cat /proc/2480/maps 
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 8669698         /tmp/test
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:05 8669698         /tmp/test
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 8669698         /tmp/test
f759f000-f75a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
f75a0000-f7740000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4465182         /lib32/libc-2.15.so
f7740000-f7741000 ---p 001a0000 08:05 4465182         /lib32/libc-2.15.so
f7741000-f7743000 r--p 001a0000 08:05 4465182         /lib32/libc-2.15.so
f7743000-f7744000 rw-p 001a2000 08:05 4465182         /lib32/libc-2.15.so
f7744000-f7748000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
f775e000-f7760000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
f7760000-f7761000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0               [vdso]
f7761000-f7781000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4465203         /lib32/ld-2.15.so  
f7781000-f7782000 r--p 0001f000 08:05 4465203         /lib32/ld-2.15.so  
f7782000-f7783000 rw-p 00020000 08:05 4465203         /lib32/ld-2.15.so  
ffc67000-ffc88000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0               [stack]
```

Where `2480` is the PID of some process that interests you (in my case I just ran a test program).

The first and second column are ranges of your address space; pointer values basically.  These ranges are known as "mappings" because they establish a range of your address space that is "mapped," meaning you can read, write, and/or execute it.  The OS sets up each mapping to correspond to some memory and/or files.  If your process tries to read, write, or execute any pointer that is not in one of these ranges, the program will segfault.  Notice that there is no mapping for the pointer value "0" -- this is how the OS guarantees that dereferencing a `NULL` pointer will crash the program.

For any pointer values in these ranges, what happens depends on the memory protections for that mapping (`r` is readable, `w` is writable, `x` is executable) and what is mapped at that address.  You'll notice my program itself (`/tmp/test`) is mapped into the address space; if I read from those regions I'll read my program's code and data.  Other ranges map in shared libraries, and the last mapping is the stack.

This all, of course, assumes that you're running a program under a memory-protected OS with a [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit); the MMU is what lets the OS set up these specific ranges that mean different things.  On a CPU without a MMU, reading through memory will just read the physical contents of all of the memory itself.